# Splitting Exception

Tags: java, exception

I want to spilt an exception, following is my exception:

[Fatal Error] Test.xml:18:23: The element type "value" must be terminated by the matching end-tag `</value>`.

Now I want to take the value 18 alone.

I tried with following code:

`System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(e.getMessage().split(":")));`

but it is printing:

`[The element type "value" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</value>".].`

How can I take the values 18 alone?

When I try with the following code:

`System.out.println(e.getMessage().toString());`, it is just printing `"The element type "value" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</value>"."`

Comment: Print your stacktrace to see the acual exception thrown by java. You would need to split based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to print the value of `18`, then something like so might help:

```
String str = "[Fatal Error] Test.xml:18:23: The element type \"value\" must be terminated by the matching end-tag ";
System.out.println(str.split(":")[1]);
```

Yields: `18`

EDIT: On 2nd thought, `e.getMessage()` will not yield you something like this string: `[Fatal Error] Test.xml:18:23: The element type "value" must be terminated by the matching end-tag </value>`. This string seems to be the product of some logging facility, so you will have to read it from file or something similar to get the value of `18` showing.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
e.getMessage().split(":")[1]
```